# Unit test won't pass when trying to throw error

Tags: javascript, express, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am a bit new to Mocha, Chai and Unit Testing. I am trying to write a basic test to check that Authorization headers are present in the request coming through my middle ware. I have tried a few things from passing the `TypeError` to `throw()` as well as message and `Error` no luck.... any help would be greatly appreciated.

**My Middleware**

```js
exports.verify = async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        const headers = req.get('Authorization');
        let decodedToken;
    
        if (!headers) {
          const error = new Error('Not Authenticated');
          error.statusCode = 401;
          throw error;
        }
        const token = headers.split(' ')[1];
    
        try {
          decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, SECRET);
        } catch (err) {
          err.statusCode = 500;
          throw err;
        }
    
        if (!decodedToken) {
          const error = new Error('Not Authenticated');
          error.statusCode = 401;
          throw error;
        }
    
        req.userUid = decodedToken.userUid;
    
        const queryRef = await users.where('uid', '==', req.userUid).get();
    
        if (queryRef.empty) {
          const error = new Error('Not Authenticated');
          error.statusCode = 401;
          throw error;
        } 
        next();
      } catch (err) {
        log.error(err);
        next(err);
      }
    };
```

**My Test**

```js
it('Should throw an error if no auth header provided.', function () {
  const req = {
    get: function () {
      return null;
    },
  };

  expect(function () {
    verify(req, {}, () => {});
  }).to.throw();
});
```

*just in case* - **Error handling at app.ts**

```js
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const status = err.statusCode || 500;
  const message = err.message;
  const data = err.data || [];
  const userUid = req.userUid;
  const stack = err.stack;
  log.error(`STATUS: ${status} - MESSAGE: ${message} - STACK: ${stack}`);
  res.status(status).json(message);
});
```

Comment: You are not throwing anything. You are catching the error. You should rather test if `next()` was called with an error argument

Comment: Trying adding a mock function for `next` then log the error. If there is an error, then you can throw from the function you are passing to `expect`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the tips everyone. After a bit more digging this passed.

*changed test to:*

**My Test**

```js
it('Should throw an error if no auth header provided.', function (done) {
  const req = {
    get: function () {
      return null;
    },
  };

  const callback = (err) => {
    if (err && err instanceof Error && err.message === 'Not Authenticated') {
      // test passed, called with an Error arg
      done();
    } else {
      // force fail the test, the `err` is not what we expect it to be
      done(new Error('Assertion failed'));
    }
  };
  verify(req, {}, callback);
});
```